# How to change the colour of the input text for the auto complete class

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my Autocomplete widget and I would like to change the input colour to be white

```
var mainscreen =  
  
  Container(
    height: 60,
    width: 385,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0), 
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.white, 
      width: 2.0,
    ),
  ),

    child: 
    
    
    Padding( 
      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 0, 20, 20),
      child: 


Autocomplete<String>(
      optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
    if (textEditingValue.text.isEmpty) {
      return const Iterable<String>.empty();
    }
    return initial_dashboard_info(textEditingValue.text);
  },
  onSelected: (String item) async {
    setState(() {
      place = item;
    });
  },
)));
```

Is there a quick fix to doing this, or do I need to create a new custom widget from scratch?

Currently this is what it looks like:

As you can see it's very hard for the user to read what they have inputted.
[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the complete screen? and make the code runnable.